# Optimize Wordpress Nginx Website with Litespeed cache

Tags: wordpress, optimization, litespeed, w3-total-cache

I'm trying to optimize my website and I've tried many ways like using WP optimizer with minification and cache, w3 total cache  with minification and more. The best score I get is whenever I use Litespeed optimization. Cache doesn't work on my nginx server but the optimization is so good that I get 65 without even using cache while I get around 40 with w3 cache. I want to improve my site speed even more and I noticed the only problem whenever I load my site is the server response time which is around 3 seconds. If I activate w3 total cache this gets close to 200ms. The problem is that I want to serve the minified and combinied version of my site from litespeed with w3 total cache or another caching plugin to eliminate that 3s response time. Is this possible and how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to enable LSCache optimization features to optimize static files, and use the cache feature from the w3-total cache plugin. The answer is yes, it's possible. As long as you have only one full-page cache feature enabled at a time, then it will have no conflict with other tools. Other features from LSCWP like Guest Mode, and Guest Optimization may not work with other tools, so you might want to test them thoroughly. If you want to utilize the cache feature from the LSCache in the future, the easiest way for you is to add the QUIC Cloud CDN in the front. Hope the above information helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You got me covered. Problem is that the client doesn't want a CDN at all for whatever reason.